# how to display the statistics about all the files in a folder in C#

Tags: c#

The output must be like this:

Files in: C:\Windows
Total files: 49
Total size of all files: 7121424 bytes
Largest file: explorer.exe, 2871808 bytes
Average file length: 145335 bytes

Comment: I'd started with creating application. You can use Visual Studio for that

Comment: Do you want the full source code in a ZIP file, or just the source files individually so that you can copy/paste them into your project?

Comment: Just look at: http://www.dotnetperls.com/fileinfo

Comment: I want it for example from the folder C:\\Windows..i've been trying everything and i can't get that output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this:

"How to: Get Information About Files, Folders, and Drives (C# Programming Guide)"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yk7a1b0.aspx

For example:

```
// Get the files in the directory and print out some information about them.
System.IO.FileInfo[] fileNames = dirInfo.GetFiles("*.*");


foreach (System.IO.FileInfo fi in fileNames)
{
       Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}: {2}", fi.Name, fi.LastAccessTime, fi.Length);
}
```

You can change the Console.WriteLine to the format that you want...