# Filtring file types C#

Tags: c#

I'm writing an console application to show folder statistics on C:\windows, and show the total files in there is there anyways it can be simplified and link the file type with the user!. This is what I've got so far:

```
               {
                    String extention = String.Empty;
                    // Prompt the user to enter extention type 
                    Console.Write("Please enter extention type: ");
                    extention = Console.ReadLine();

                    // This gets the Folder location which in this case is C:\\windows
                    DirectoryInfo root = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows));

                    // This is basicly the bit that collects the data after the user has entered the extention type

                    FileInfo[] executables = root.GetFiles("*exe");

                    foreach (var exe in executables)
                    {
                        //This will show the word txt in the console window
                        Console.WriteLine(exe.Name);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        {
            String extention2 = String.Empty;

            // Prompt the user to enter extention type
            extention2 = Console.ReadLine();

            // This gets the Folder location which in this case is C:\\windows
            DirectoryInfo root2 = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows));

            FileInfo[] text = root2.GetFiles("*.txt");

            foreach (var txt in text)
            {
                //This will show the word txt in the console window
                Console.WriteLine(txt.Name);
            }
        }

            String extention4 = String.Empty;

            // Prompt the user to enter extention type
            extention4 = Console.ReadLine();

            // This gets the Folder location which in this case is C:\\windows
            DirectoryInfo root4 = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows));

            FileInfo[] windows = root4.GetFiles("*.win");

            foreach (var win in windows)
            {
                //This will show the word txt in the console window
                Console.WriteLine(win.Name);
            }
```

Comment: Look at this topic:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20881645/how-to-display-the-statistics-about-all-the-files-in-a-folder-in-c-sharp/20881751#20881751

Answer (score 2):

Try using: `new DirectoryInfo("C:\\Windows")`

If you want to get a list of the files in that directory then call:

```
EnumerateFiles("*",SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

on the DirectoryInfo  object

Answer (score 1):

Look at this:

"How to: Get Information About Files, Folders, and Drives (C# Programming Guide)"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yk7a1b0.aspx

For example:

```
// Get the files in the directory and print out some information about them.
System.IO.FileInfo[] fileNames = dirInfo.GetFiles("*.*");


foreach (System.IO.FileInfo fi in fileNames)
{
       Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}: {2}", fi.Name, fi.LastAccessTime, fi.Length);
}
```

You can change the Console.WriteLine to the format that you want...

**Update:**

```
  System.IO.DriveInfo di = new System.IO.DriveInfo(@"C:\");

  // Get the root directory
  System.IO.DirectoryInfo dirInfo = di.RootDirectory;

  // And then you can do .GetFiles()
  System.IO.FileInfo[] fileNames = dirInfo.GetFiles("*.*");
```

Comment: Hi i'm a student still learning and ive fixed firInfo by changing it to Info... but there is nothing linking to the GetFiles could you please help so the virile is correctly declared

Comment: See Update in my post. (Do you mean how you can access the .GetFiles() method?)